# How to fix "Required MutableLiveData<String> but 'SwitchMap' was inferred to LiveData<Y>" when using Transformations.switchMap?

Tags: android, android-livedata, switchmap

I am trying to use ViewModel with some LiveData that uses the value from another LiveData.

For that I am trying to use `Transformations.switchMap` but I am getting

> Incompatible types. Required MutableLiveData but 'switchMap'
>   was inferred to LiveData: no instance(s) of type variable(s) Y
>   exist so that LiveData conforms to MutableLiveData

I have already tried to switch to `Transformations.map`, but with the same results.

```
public class RestaurantViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<FirebaseUser> userLiveData  = new MutableLiveData<>();

    private final MutableLiveData<String> userId =
    Transformations.switchMap(userLiveData, input -> {
        return input.getUid();
    });

    private String getUid(FirebaseUser user){
        return user.getUid();
    }

    private void setUser(FirebaseUser currentUser){
        this.userLiveData.setValue(currentUser);}
}
```

I expected the userId to be dependent on the value of userLiveData, but I am can't do it.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, **`Transformations.switchMap`** returns `LiveData` while your receiver type is `MutableLiveData`. consider changing like below :

```
private final LiveData<String> userId = Transformations.switchMap(userLiveData, input -> {
    return input.getUid();
}); // Here we change userId 'MutableLiveData' to 'LiveData'.
```

Check [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations#switchmap).